# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Ошибка: пустой массив

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Знаю такой вопрос уже есть в англоязычной stackoverflow.. Но мне не помогло ответ.. Думаю, ошибка в получение данных от сервера.. Я сделал эту же вопрос(с этим кодом) на другой сервер(`https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=`).. Все работал как надо.. 
Код:

```js
const API = 'http://46.101.146.101:8081/universities';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [], // Попробовал без массива))
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });

    fetch(API)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Что-то пошла не так...');
        }
      })
      .then(responseJSON => {
        this.setState({
          data: responseJSON.data,
          isLoading: false
        })
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({
        error,
        isLoading: false
      }));
  }

  render() {
    const {
      data,
      isLoading,
      error
    } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p className = 'SMS' > Loading... < /p>;
    }

    if (error) {
      return <p className = 'SMS' > {
        error.message
      } < /p>;
    }

    return ( <
      div id = 'container' > {
        data.map(data =>
          <
          div className = "content"
          key = {
            data.id
          } >
          <
          img src = {
            data.main_image_url
          }
          /> <
          h3 className = "title" > {
            data.title
          } < /h3> <
          div className = "description_content" >
          <
          p className = "description" > {
            data.description
          } < /p> < /
          div > <
          /div>
        )
      }; <
      /div>
    );
  }
}


const Container = document.querySelector('main');
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , Container);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://soulwire.github.io/sketch.js/js/sketch.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Думаю, я неправильно получаю данные от сервера или не понимаю в чем проблема.. Как мне это исправит? 
A когда сделал `data: [[]]` требовал ключ.. Но я ключ сделал..

P.S. Кто может изменить вопрос чтобы возможно было выполнит код?

Comment: Судя по данным, который возвращает API вам надо: 1) Добавить формат данных `/?format=json` 2) `responseJSON.data` вот это заменить на `responseJSON`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо помогло!! Я несколько часов сидел чтобы исправить это :( А тут за 5 минут помогли мне..

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ответы - в ответы, иначе этот вопрос будет бесполезен, так как комментарии читают не всегда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас был не верный запрос к АПИ.

```js
const API = 'http://46.101.146.101:8081/universities/?format=json';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [], // Попробовал без массива))
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true
    });

    fetch(API)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Что-то пошла не так...');
        }
      })
      .then(responseJSON => {
        this.setState({
          data: responseJSON,
          isLoading: false
        })
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({
        error,
        isLoading: false
      }));
  }

  render() {
    const {
      data,
      isLoading,
      error
    } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p className = 'SMS' > Loading... < /p>;
    }

    if (error) {
      return <p className = 'SMS' > {
        error.message
      } < /p>;
    }

    return ( <
      div id = 'container' > {
        data.map(data =>
          <
          div className = "content"
          key = {
            data.id
          } >
          <
          img src = {
            data.main_image_url
          }
          /> <
          h3 className = "title" > {
            data.title
          } < /h3> <
          div className = "description_content" >
          <
          p className = "description" > {
            data.description
          } < /p> < /
          div > <
          /div>
        )
      }; <
      /div>
    );
  }
}


const Container = document.querySelector('main');
ReactDOM.render( < App / > , Container);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://soulwire.github.io/sketch.js/js/sketch.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```